# Cucumber test not deleting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, configuration, cucumber

I have a project with several features in cucumber both plain and selenium are failing indicating problems when trying to create a user because of the email uniqness validation (so the records are not being deleted and every background on the feature is failing)

I get a warning like this "WARNING: You have set Rails' config.cache_classes to false (most likely in config/environments/cucumber.rb).  This setting is known to break Cucumber's use_transactional_fixtures method. Set config.cache_classes to true if you want to use transactional fixtures.  For more information see https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211/tickets/165."

Weird enough all my enviroments have the session_cache set to true (just development hast it on false but I also tried setting it to true and run it)

Also the same project is working on other computers I tried uninstaling ruby and all the gems from rvm and reinstall but I still get the same error

Any ideas what else i could try to solve this on my mac? also database cleaning strategy is set to fixtures

I appreciate your time

Comment: sorry it is cache_classes that are set to true in every environment

Comment: Did you check config/environments/cucumber.rb?

Comment: Yeah it is set to true everywhere but in development but I have also tried changing that one into true stills give me the same message and fails on the backgrounds where Iam creating a user (fails because the email is already being taken)

Comment: I just noticed that when i set the cache_classes on the development.rb the warning does not appear (it still fails) and when I add RAILS_ENV=test it runs but many of the test fails with Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED), is it somehow taking development enviroment instead of test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using a hook to clear out the data.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

A before hook that will do a .destroy on all records to ensure a clean start may be a good bet.  It feels hacky to me, but may help you further diagnose the failure.